How to get usage metadata while using JSON output parser
Idea: To get the JSON response of some type using lanchain js, and also i want to get metadata details like usage and all.
async generateQuestionsForSummary(jobTitle: string, type: string): Promise<GenAIQuestionsDto> {
    const prompt = new PromptTemplate({
      template: `<<TEMPLATE>>`,
      inputVariables: ["type"],
    });
    const formattedPrompt = await prompt.format({
      type,
    });
    console.log("Formatted Prompt:", formattedPrompt);
    // Set up a parser + inject instructions into the prompt template.
    const parser = new LoggingJsonOutputParser<ResponseModel>();
    const chain = prompt.pipe(this.gemini).pipe(parser);
    const response = await chain.invoke({ type, jobTitle });
    return response;
}

I tried to log the input, but in this also I don't have metadata details, getting just the JSON string.
class LoggingJsonOutputParser<T> extends JsonOutputParser<T> {
  async parse(response: string): Promise<T> {
    console.log("Unstructured Response:", response); // Log the unstructured response
    return super.parse(response); // Call the original parse method
  }
}

I am getting the JSON response successfully but I am unable to get the usage and metadata details.
